# Scrape next page content beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I'm trying to scrape [this](https://www.detik.com/terpopuler) news website. I can scrape news article from each topics there. But sometimes the articles page contain more than 1 page in there like [this](https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5248290/tragis-nasib-rangga-tewas-usai-palak-uang-rokok-ke-siswa-sma?_ga=2.5342323.1583866830.1604849107-1664116409.1580562887). The next page had the same HTML structure like the first page. Is there any way to automatically scrape the rest of articles on the next page if there is more than one page in there?

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import csv

detik = requests.get('https://www.detik.com/terpopuler')
beautify = BeautifulSoup(detik.content, 'html5lib')

news = beautify.find_all('article', {'class','list-content__item'})
arti = []
for each in news:
  try:
    title = each.find('h3', {'class','media__title'}).text
    lnk = each.a.get('href')

    r = requests.get(lnk)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html5lib')
    content = soup.find('div', {'class', 'detail__body-text itp_bodycontent'}).text.strip()

    print(title)
    print(lnk)

    arti.append({
      'Headline': title,
      'Content':content,
      'Link': lnk
    })
  except:
    continue
df = pd.DataFrame(arti)
df.to_csv('detik.csv', index=False)
```

This is the next page button image. "Selanjutnya" means next, and "Halaman" means page.

[image]

Really appreciated if you willing to help.

Answer (score 0):

the way you would approach this is first write a separate function to extract info from article page and then check if there is any pagination on the article page by checking for this class "detail__anchor-numb" and you would loop through the pages
and extract data from article:

```
pages= soup.select('.detail__anchor-numb')
if len(pages):
    page_links= [i.attrs.get('href') for i in soup.select('.detail__anchor-numb')]
    for page in range(1, len(page_links)+1):
        #scrape_article function will handle requesting a url and getting data from article
        next_article_url = page_links[page ]
        scrape_article(next_article_url)
```

I hope that answers your question